# Backbone: Attaching event to this.$el and re rendering causes multiple events to be bound

Tags: events, backbone.js

I need to attach an event to the main view element, this.$el.  In this case its an 'LI'.  Then I need to re render this view sometimes.  The problem is if i re render it, it attaches any events in the onRender method that is attached to this.$el each time its rendered.  So if i call this.render() 3 times the handler gets attached 3 times.  However, if i attach the event to a childNode of this.$el, this does not happen and the events seem to be automatically undelegated and added back on each render.  The problem is I NEED to use the main this.$el element in this case.

Is this a bug?  Shouldn't this.$el function like the childNodes?  Should I not be attaching things to this.$el?

inside the view:

```
onRender: function(){
    this.$el.on('click', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Can't you delegate the eventhandler to the body, or a higher element, so that you don't need to register one each time you add/remove an element?

Comment: I added a small preview that hopefully shows what im doing

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using the view's event hash to attach this listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to [use the view's event hash](https://jsfiddle.net/7mMGp/119/), you could do the following:

```
var Bookmark = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': function() {
            console.log('bound once')
        }
    }
    ...});
```

If for some reason that's not an option, you could [explicitly remove any existing event listeners for this event in the render method](https://jsfiddle.net/7mMGp/120/), which will prevent the listener from being attached multiple times:

```
var Bookmark = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    render: function(x) {
        this.$el.off('click.render-click');
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.$el.on('click.render-click', function () { 
            console.log('only ever bound once');
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no idea why I'm not using the event hash.  I didn't realize its function.  I'm a bit new to BB.  Thank you!